# Nativescript tab page textfield

Tags: nativescript

I can't get the value from my bound textfield.  I used the tab template.  On the Microsoft Android Emulator.  Is there something I need to add to the main tab page view model maybe?

View

```
<GridLayout class="page-content">
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <Label class="page-icon fa" text="&#xf002;"></Label>
        <TextField id="txtSearch" text="{{ search }}" hint="Search" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" />
        <Button text="Sign in" tap="searchClick" />
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
var SearchViewModel = require("./search-view-model");

var svm = new SearchViewModel();

function onLoaded(args) {
    var component = args.object;
    component.bindingContext = new SearchViewModel();
}

exports.searchClick = function() {    

    svm.searches()
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            dialogsModule.alert({
                message: "Unfortunately we could not find your account.",
                okButtonText: "OK"
            });
            return Promise.reject();
        })
        .then(function() {
            //frameModule.topmost().navigate("views/list/list");
        });
};

exports.onLoaded = onLoaded;
```

**model**
For some reason viewModel.get("search") returns nothing.  The button fires fine.

```
const observableModule = require("data/observable");
var fetchModule = require("fetch");

//Info is the returning object
function SearchViewModel(info) {
    info = info || {};

    var viewModel = new observableModule.fromObject({
           search: info.search || ""
    });

    viewModel.searches = function() {
        var test = viewModel.get("search");
        return fetchModule.fetch(config.apiUrl + viewModel.get("search"), {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            config.token = data.Result.access_token;
        });
    };

    return viewModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `this.search`,
Or you can use `this.get("search")`

Edit: also on a side note,
In your code behind file, you are creating

`var svm = new SearchViewModel();`

But you are not assigning svm as the bindingContext, instead you are creating a new instance of SearchViewModel. That might cause some unexpected behavior later.

Comment: No difference using this.get("search")  
Sorry, I didn't paste the click event that uses the svm.  I'll add it.  Is there another way to use component in it's place?

Comment: Just do this. In your code behind, write, `component.bindingContext = svm;` instead of  current line

Comment: Actually tried that too.  Looks like my onLoaded function is never hit or at least it's not hitting my break point.  So the bindings never happen.

Comment: Can you also share the xml?

Comment: These tab pages are like partial views I guess.  I didn't see a way to add loaded to the GridLayout tag.  The main page is in the tabs-page.xml.  I think there's a way to get the tab loaded event though.

Comment: On the GridLayout you have to set, `loaded="onLoaded"`

Comment: Also don't forget to make the changes that I suggested in the 2nd comment. That is essential for this to work.

Comment: That worked, though I tried it before so I guess it was the combination of the two answers. :)   Thanks!